# setting primary key for a database not named ":id"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using: rails 2.3.5 ruby 1.8.7 and Windows 7 Home Basic

I was given a database and I connected it to rails, having no problems reading and getting data from it. Now what I want to do is add some functionality in it (add, edit and delete) but when I try to set my primary key to the table's primary key (ProductCode) by doing this code:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
self.primary_key :ProductCode
end
```

I got this error when doing a `@products = Product.find(:all, :limit => 10)`:

ArgumentError in PosController#index
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

How can I solve this ?

Here's my controller's code:

```
    class PosController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @cards = Card.find(:all)
        @products = Product.find(:all, :limit => 10)
    end

    def new
        @pro = Product.new
    end

    def edit
    @pro = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
    @pro = Product.find(params[:id])
    if session[:user_id]
                @log = "Welcome Administrator!"
                @logout="logout"
            else
                @log = "Admin Log in"
                @logout=""
            end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pro.update_attributes(params[:product])
        flash[:notice] = 'product was successfully updated.'
        format.html { redirect_to(:controller => "pos", :action => "index") }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @pro.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

    def create
    @pro = Product.new(params[:product])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pro.save
        flash[:notice] = 'product was successfully created.'
        format.html {redirect_to (:controller => "pos", :action => "index")}
        #format.xml  { render :xml => @product, :status => :created, :location => @product }
      else
        format.html { render :controller => "pos",:action => "new" }
        #format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @pro = Product.find(params[:id])
    @pro.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
    flash[:notice] = 'product was successfully deleted.'
      format.html { redirect_to(:controller => "pos", :action => "index") }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Just a note: "ProductCode" is not an idiomatic rails' column name. Should be `product_code`.

Comment: But it's the column name in my database. should i also rename it to "product_code"?

Comment: Well, yes, I would. It's not affecting performance. But it might cause you troubles somewhere, because Rails preaches "convention over configuration" and assumes many things. One of these things is that database names are in snake_case.

Comment: still didn't solve the argumentError :(

Comment: Yes, that's why it's a hint, not an answer :)

Comment: please past the code of your controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sets the name of the primary key column.

self.primary_key = "product_code"

Answer (score 3):

`self.primary_key` returns what rails currently thinks is the primary key and hence takes no arguments. If you want to set the primary key, use `self.primary_key = 'blah'`.

Earlier versions of rails also supported `set_primary_key 'blah'`, but this was deprecated in rails 3.2.