# Rails (rake) default ID field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rake, rails-migrations

When creating a table on my pgslq db with rake, rails allways create an "id" field as primary key.

My issue is that i need to have the id field with a custom name. How can i specify the database fields with ONLY the fields i want, specifying the primary key?

Comment: This is covered in [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986658/setting-primary-key-for-a-database-not-named-id) [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200568/using-rails-how-can-i-set-my-primary-key-to-not-be-an-integer-typed-column) Stack Overflow questions and [all over the web](http://roninonrails.blogspot.com/2008/06/using-non-standard-primary-keys-with.html), but I'll just add that it's going to make your life hell, and you should do everything in your power to switch to using `id` in your tables if possible.  It's a major fault of Rails, but `id` makes things Just Work.

Comment: Downvote for not searching SO before posting a redundant question.

Comment: I did a quick search about it and failed to found anything. Thanx for the extra info about the problem of not using the ID with the default name... The problem was because the data model we have, now we are re discussing about it.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify primary key passing its name to `create_table` in migration:

```
create_table :my_table, :primary_key => :custom_id do |t|
  #...
end
```